# How to display data from different tables when they have the same hour (datetime) using Google Charts and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to display multidimensional data from different tables, when there is a match in hour. So for example, value1 from table1 and value2 from table2 should be displayed in Y and the hour in X. I'm using Google Charts and MySQL. The code works when I select things from a single table, but when I try to mix results it gives this error:  'Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string'

I've tried to use WHERE and tried JOIN for linking the column Datetime from table1 with table2, but no success. I know I may still have to format Datetime to pick up the hour only, but I'm feeling completely stuck.

Here is what I have in table 1:

[image]

And in table 2:

[image]

I'm looking to have something like this:

[image]

Below is the code:

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

 ['Datetime','Value1', 'Value2'],
 <?php 

 $query =   "SELECT table1.Datetime, table1.Value1, table2.Value2 ".
            "FROM table1 ".
            "WHERE table1.Datetime = table2.Datetime ".
            "ORDER BY table1.Datetime ASC ".
            "LIMIT 24";

             $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

             echo "[
             '".$row['Datetime']."',
             ".$row['Value1']." ,
             ".$row['Value2']."
             ],";
             }
             ?>     

 ]);
```

Note: I'm limiting the chart to 24 rows, as when new data is inserted (every hour), only the last 24 hours of data are displayed.

Comment: given the sql above, you would need to include `table2` in the `FROM` statement --> `FROM table1, table2`

Comment: I tried this as well, but then it seems that the rows start to repeat. The chart displays more than 4 rows. :/

Comment: when the rows repeat, that typically means there are more than one row in each table that meets the criteria in the `WHERE` statement -- for instance, in the example tables you have provided, there are 3 rows in each table with a date of `2019-06-04 00:00:00`, since `WHERE` only states `table1.Datetime = table2.Datetime`, this will cause repeating rows -- do you want to sum the values for those rows?

Comment: I see.. I don't want to 'sum' the values, what I need to have in the chart is:
2019-06-04 00:00:00 - 50 and 80 (from ID1, value 1/table1 and value 2/table2)
2019-06-04 00:00:00 - 30 and 20 (from ID2)
2019-06-04 00:00:00 - 66 and 34 (from ID3)
2019-06-04 15:01:10 - 44 and 33 (from ID4)

Comment: change the `WHERE` statement --> `WHERE table1.Datetime = table2.Datetime and table1.ID = table2.ID`

Comment: yes, that works..but I didn't want to have to compare the ID. But actually now I understand what was happening, as you pointed out above, I can't compare the Datetime and have repetitions of the same Datetime value. In the real application I won't have this problem, it was just a silly mistake of using this Datetime values for testing.
In the real application I will have different Datetime so this should work. Now I just need to format the output to show the hour only. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, but this was thanks to the feedback provided in the comments by WhiteHat.

First problem: I was not including the second table in the FROM clause.

Second problem: My data example was not good as I had repetitions of the Datetime values.

Third problem: Matching the hour between tables was solved by adding the HOUR function in the code. See below:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

 ['Hour1','Value1', 'Value2'],
 <?php 

 $query =   "SELECT HOUR(table1.Datetime) AS Hour1, table1.Value1, table2.Value2 ".
            "FROM table1, table2 ".
            "WHERE HOUR(table1.Datetime) = HOUR(table2.Datetime) ".
            "ORDER BY table1.Datetime ASC ".
            "LIMIT 24";

             $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

             echo "[
             '".$row['Hour1']."',
             ".$row['Value1']." ,
             ".$row['Value2']."
             ],";
             }
             ?>


 ]);
```